# To what extent can MAMP be hacked?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, localhost, mamp, virus

I am running Wordpress on a local development server to test plugins from 'dubious' sources. I believe I've been hacked after installing an unofficial copy of a plugin. Now I'm looking for help to assess how serious this may be and how to proceed.

Here's what exactly went down:

1. Installed MAMP (4.2) on my Mac (10.14.6), with htdocs in it's default location (in the MAMP application folder)
2. Installed multiple Wordpress sites to develop for clients over several months
3. Used one of these existing, old, dev sites to test plugins before purchase
4. I began to install a plugin .zip file, however after I clicked "activate" I was asked by macos whether to allow MAMP access to photos, and then to calendar, both of which I denied. The activation failed due to a "Fatal Error".
5. I ditched this plugin and moved onto the next. The next one also failed due to fatal error, this time with the error message: "Fatal error: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement or after any declare call in the script in"
6. Googled this message revealing it's common when hacked.

So, does the hacker have any access to this website? To the entire local server? To my entire computer where MAMP is installed?

Am I in the clear just deleting the plugin? Clean install MAMP?

Thanks.

Comment: The message about the namespace isn't really an indication of your website being backed. More like PHP is telling you that some script on your site (a plugin I suppose) isn't using namespaces properly: as the notice says, namespaces should be the first thing PHP reads (excluding comments) when parsing a PHP file. If you place your namespace somewhere else (eg. you set a variable first, then declare the namespace) you'll get that message.

Comment: Gotcha, however searching for answers I've found quite a few cases discussed where malware was deemed the culprit for the additional script in a plugin's PHP. I get what you're saying though, I appreciate the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress hacks tend to be more about collecting information from WordPress.

Anytime you get a warning like that, it should tell you where the issue is.

However, I would install Wordfence on your local sites and have it run a scan. It will compare core files etc to what is on the repo and tell you. It will get about 99% of it unless it is a Zero day.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm pretty sure I get it, and this could be ridiculous, but could you just clarify whether it's collecting information off that one WP site, or can it worm it's way through a database collecting from all WP sites, present and future, on that server?

Comment: Impossible to answer that without seeing what it is doing.